# How to execute second request based on previous request result in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter-3.2

I have 2 subsequent request. If first request result is Success then i want to execute second request in JMETER else don't want to execute second request. So how do i do that? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set Thread Groups `Action to be taken on sample error` set to "`Start new Thread Group`" , This will tell JMeter to stop executing subsequent samplers  when a sampler fails.

you can use Assertions to verify whether the request is successful or not , When an Assertion is failed JMEter marks the saample as failed and it wont execute subsequent requests if you mention `Start new Thread Group` option in thread group Configuration

More information:

[Thread Groups in JMeter](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/05/guide-jmeter-thread-groups/)